# Yii2-How to add two excel sheet in one excel file

Tags: excel, email, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am working with `swift mail` in `yii2`. I am sending an email with `csv` attachment. The file contains one sheet. Now I want to add two sheets in one file.

```
  public function actionEmail()
{
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT od.`meter_serial`) AS OGP_Created, 
            COUNT(DISTINCT mp.`meter_id`) AS Un_Verified_Meters, 
            COUNT(DISTINCT ins.`meter_msn`) AS Verified_Meters, 
            sd.`sub_div_code` AS SD_Code,sd.`name` AS SD_Name
            FROM `ogp_detail` od
            INNER JOIN `survey_hesco_subdivision` sd ON od.`sub_div` = sd.`sub_div_code`
            LEFT JOIN `meter_ping` mp ON od.`meter_id` = mp.`meter_id`
            LEFT JOIN `installations` ins ON od.`meter_serial` = ins.`meter_msn`
            WHERE od.`meter_type` = '3-Phase'
            GROUP BY sd.`name`";

    $query= "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT od.`meter_serial`) AS OGP_Created, 
             COUNT(DISTINCT mp.`meter_id`) AS Un_Verified_Meters, 
             COUNT(DISTINCT ins.`meter_msn`) AS Verified_Meters, 
             sd.`sub_div_code` AS SD_Code,sd.`name` AS SD_Name
             FROM `ogp_detail` od
             INNER JOIN `survey_hesco_subdivision` sd ON od.`sub_div` = 
             sd.`sub_div_code`
             LEFT JOIN `meter_ping` mp ON od.`meter_id` = mp.`meter_id`
             LEFT JOIN `installations` ins ON od.`meter_serial` = 
             ins.`meter_msn`
             WHERE od.`meter_type` = 'L.T.TOU'
             GROUP BY sd.`name`";

    $result = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();

    $result_set = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();

    //create a csv file
    $filename   =   $this->getAttachment($result,$result_set);

    //send email
    $this->sendEmail($filename);


    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

Below is my `getAttachment` function

```
 public function getAttachment($results,$result_set) {
    $sum_OGP = 0;
    $sum_UnVerified = 0;
    $sum_Verified = 0;

    $filename = Yii::getAlias('@webroot') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '3-Phase Breakdown List ' . date('d-m-y') . '.csv';

    //open a csv file
    $file = fopen($filename, "w");

    $headerInjected = false;
    $header = ['OGP Created', '3-Phase Un Verified Meters', '3-Phase Verified Meters', 'Sub Div Code', 'Sub Div Name'];

    //write lines to the csv file
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        if (!$headerInjected) {
            $headerInjected = true;
            fputcsv($file, $header);
        }
        fputcsv($file, $result);
        $sum_OGP +=$result['OGP_Created'];
        $sum_UnVerified +=$result['Un_Verified_Meters'];
        $sum_Verified +=$result['Verified_Meters'];
    }

    //add the sum in the last row
    fputcsv($file,["Total OGP","Total Unverified Meters","Total Verified Meters"]);
    fputcsv($file,[$sum_OGP,$sum_UnVerified,$sum_Verified]);

    //close the file handle
    fclose($file);
    return $filename;
}
```

I want to add the contents of `$result_set` the `header` for both will be same the `fputcsv` contents will be different.

How can I add both of them in one excel file with two sheets?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: In excel you can move or copy sheets between files.

Comment: can you please provide a sample for it ?

Comment: I just right click on the tab in excel and use move / copy... But in vba I have used Workbooks(“filename.xlsx”.Sheets(sheetname).Move Before:=NewCaseFile.Sheets(1)

Comment: you cannot do that when using `CSV` files, `CSV` is a very simple format, and does not have the concept of a "sheet".  use the other utility i told you yesterday

Comment: I have tried to use that utility but as a newbie I am unable to do it properly :|